# Link contents of directory from outside of a samba share inside that share

Tags: samba, network-share

I have a samba share at `/public`. The directory allows only reading from users that are connecting to it but any user on the server can write to it.

I have a folder in my home directory at `~/processing`. I want to "link" (not sure if that is the correct term) all files from that folder to `/public` and have it be accessible by users connecting to the share.

Finally, I would like this link to happen once, so I wouldn't need to constantly poll for new files with some `cron` script or something (which is an option, but not an ideal one for me).

My samba config is at [this PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/pciFb8gY).

I have root access on the server so I can pretty much do anything I need to to get this working. Additionally, if it comes down to it I can just put the files directly into the `/public` folder, although I would rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set

```
wide links = no
```

you can use symlinks; otherwise `mount --bind` the relevant path inside your share.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it worked. But I can't see the files on the actual file system, only in the share. Is that something that is expected to happen?